# CSS absolute position over variable height

Tags: html, css

I have two div's inside a parent div. I want to place the divs so that the div 1 position is absolute at `bottom:0` of parent div, and the div 2 is always on the top of the div 1.

I am using absolute position to place the divs. However the problem is that the div 1 has variable height. How can I place the div 2 on the top of the div 1 in that case?
Please see the attached image:
[image]

I am trying this, but it does not work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="wrap">
       <div class="box2">box 2</div>
       <div class="box1">box1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box1{
    background: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.box2{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/P46ht/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.

Try this - basically removing the positions from the boxes, and setting the width on `.wrap`:

```
.wrap{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left:0;right:0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box1{
    background: yellow;
}

.box2{
    background: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/P46ht/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try it like that ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P46ht/4/)):

```
.wrap{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box1{
    background: yellow;
}

.box2{
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}
```